# Write to Mifare sector NFC RFIDIOT Python

Tags: python, nfc, mifare

I'm trying to write a number to sector 10 / block 40 on a Mifare 4k classic card

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Here is my code:

```html
BLOCK = 40
KEY = 'FFFFFFFFFFFF'
TYPE = 'AA'

import rfidiot
import re

card = rfidiot.card
if card.select():
    'card selected UID: ' + str(card.uid)
    if card.login(BLOCK, TYPE, KEY):
        if card.readMIFAREblock(BLOCK):
            print card.MIFAREdata
            data = card.ReadablePrint(card.ToBinary(card.MIFAREdata))
            id = re.findall('\d+', data)[0]
            print id

            if card.writeblock(BLOCK, '1234567'):
                print 'write success'
            else:
                 print 'error %s %s' % (card.errorcode , card.ISO7816ErrorCodes[card.errorcode])
        else:
            print 'read failed'
    else:
        print 'Login failed'
```

ouput+ error message:

```html
card selected UID: DBF93873
33333735353334000000000000000000
3375534
error 6300 No information given
```

Comment: Block 40?  In Mifare classic 4k -- the first 32 sectors contain 3 blocks and the last 8 sectors contain 15 blocks for storing data

Comment: I have no experience in **RFIDIOT**, I normally use [**pyscard**](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/) -- may worth taking a look, and just send manufacturer's specific **APDU**. Write command should start with `A0...` so I'm not sure what's going on with your send & response.